# Smart Contract Minting Limit per wallet address

Tags: solidity, nft, smart-contract-wallets

learning solidity and curious how i can limit the minting of my NFT to only 1 per address.

Trying to prevent people from minting and transferring to their other wallets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You would need ot put check in place both at minting and transfering. Would go something like this assumng you are doing it from scratch:

```
mapping(address => boolean) private _owners;
function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
    require(!_owners(to), "This address already has a token");
    ...
}

function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual {
   require(!_owners(to), "This address already has a token");
   ...
}
```

You could also use a modifier and use on both functions:

```
modifier notOwner(address to){
  require(!_owners(to), "This address already has a token");
  _;
}
```